# Training an algorithm to recognise a fuse

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision

Is it possible to train a machine learning algorithm to recognise an image of a fuse (the fuse shapes are the same, only colors change). Up until now I have been using KMeans Clustering to get the dominant color in an image and using that to describe a fuse's color. This approach is somewhat sensitive to lighting changes.

SIFT/SURF don't work so well here because they do not use colour information and also aren't able to find a decent number of matches.

However, I have been wondering if it is possible to use machine learning such that my software can recognise the image of a particular fuse and go "This fuse is brown!"

I have a bit of background in Computer Vision but very little when it comes to Machine Learning. This is somewhat of an exercise that I want to use to get into Machine Learning.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can do this by simple color thresholding. Try using HSV or LAB colorspace, should work fine. @Dima suggested color thresholder app can give you a quick idea if this can be done just by using color. If images have different illumination you can try a simple [gamma correction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_correction) and apply it to all images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Color histograms of different colors fed in to Support Vector Machines(SVM) can help in this kind of problems. Both Matlab and OpenCV come with SVM implementations so you can try them fairly quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [Color Thresholder App](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/image-segmentation-using-the-color-thesholder-app.html) in MATLAB. It gives you an easy way to experiment with different color spaces.